# How to handle Feign Client response as JSONObject

Tags: spring-boot, gson, microservices, feign

Service A returning response as gson.JsonObject. From Service B calling Service A with Feign Client. How to handle response? Tried below:

```
@FeignClient(name = "ABC")
public interface TestDataProviderApi {
   @GetMapping(value = "/v1/path/{data-type}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    **JsonObject** getData(@PathVariable("data-type") String dataType);
}

@FeignClient(name = "ABC")
public interface TestDataProviderApi {
   @GetMapping(value = "/v1/path/{data-type}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    **Object** getData(@PathVariable("data-type") String dataType);
}

@FeignClient(name = "ABC")
public interface TestDataProviderApi {
   @GetMapping(value = "/v1/path/{data-type}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    **JSONObject** getData(@PathVariable("data-type") String dataType);
}
```

Nothing worked. Either response is printed as {} or JSON exceptions. But at Service A logs states it returned proper JSON like {"a":1}. How to handle the value? The end goal is to read responses from feign client and get value using Jayway JsonPath.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: you can't return a ResponseEntity<Object>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot using jackson serialization-de-serialization by default. As object returned is of type gson, adding below property worked to receive proper response with type: JsonObject.

```
spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson
```

But this affected other controller and client behaviors as everything started expecting gson objects (not able to de-serialize JSONObjects).

Instead, at feign client marking return type as `Object` and in service layer used type conversion with `Gson()` helped.

Comment: Addition for the second part of your reply. Gson(Object) to String: gson.toJson(object); , Gson(String) to specific Object(MyObjec): gson.fromJson(gsonString, MyObject.class)

Answer (score 0):

The good property is:

```
spring.mvc.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson
```

[Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#application-properties.web.spring.mvc.converters.preferred-json-mapper)